# Disk Encryption - Extended Boot Record protection

Tags: disk-encryption, boot, opal-2.0

I posted something like this on SuperUser some months ago, but thought I'd try the security focused site. Anyway, I am working on a Disk Encryption project using OPAL drives. The OS is Linux, and is contained on an extended partition. This partition contains a root, /var, and log partition. For each of these, there is a separate locking range defined for each "header" or EBR in the extended partition. That is, I have 3 bands used simply to contain the EBR for each of my root, /var, and log partitions. The designers of the solution are no longer in the picture, so I am hoping for some insight as to why these ranges may be defined as they are. Is there a security vulnerability involved with exposing an EBR (allowing write access to it)? Specifically, anything other than evil maid attacks?

Comment: Can you add a link to the previous question?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/955498/first-32kb-of-logical-partitions-what-is-there-consequences-of-allowing-limiti